# Spring mongodb return unwind property is no longer a list

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mongodb

With mongodb [unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) I am able to sort with the property inside the array.
Since I unwinded it, the original POJO is no longer a valid one. I have to either create a new POJO or maybe use mongo [group with push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/#grp._S_push).

Is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. It is is generally the nature of aggregation pipelines that they "transform" documents from one form to another. Rarely would you ever return the document in the original query form from such a process. Of course there is always the option to use an "un-typed" form of return. But again, it depends on that being the sort of result you want.